# Securing an webhook in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

i created a webhoo on bitbucket, and want to make it secure with a secret token (or any other method). The manual describes how to use a secret token for securing a webhook:

https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/#setting-your-secret-token

But when i create a new webhook there is no field or secret box as described in the manual. Is the manual wrong or outdated? Or do i miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: Your documentation is for github, not bitbucket.  As of 15-Jul-2020, this feature has not been implemented. [source](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-12195)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jk622: 
Your documentation is for github, not bitbucket. As of 15-Jul-2020, this feature has not been implemented.